# Regex to validate following types of Patterns

Tags: php, regex, string

I am a newbie to Regex and currently developing a website in Php. As far as I have learned Regex, I have created following regex patterns to match against values. There are 2 regex I have created to validate my inputs.

**1)** First one, I want to create a regex that can allow an optional substring which is `not`

```
456,88,not,398     //True
not,934,3094,not   //true
not,389,383        //True
394,588,not        //True
694,20,589         //True
493                //True
not                //True
344,not,           //False
,not               //False
```

I have created following regex

```
/^\d*(,?not,?)*(,\d+)*$/
```

but this fails for

```
not,934,3094,not    //<--Fails
389,not,            //<--It returns true while I want it false
,not,               //<--It returns true while it should be false
```

What can be a good regex for above requirements?

---

**2)** Second one, I have created a regex to validate following strings

```
983,9,4|499,5,3|123,8,8    //true
983,9,4                    //true
```

My Regex is working good for first one but fails for second

```
/^(((\d+,)*\d+)\|((\d+,)*\d+))*$/
```

Comment: Your regexp only allows one `not`.

Comment: I don't think regexp is the best method for this. Use `explode()` to split the string on commas, and then see if the elements of that array fit fit your rules.

Comment: @Barmar yes and also fails for many other strings as I have mentioned

Comment: @Barmar may be but then I will have to explode and loop through each array item and check if it's ok or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first, use this regexp:

```
/^(\d+|not)(,(\d+|not))*$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hH3xR9/1)

For the second, you can use a regexp. You need to make the `|` part of the repeated group.

```
/^(\d+,)*\d+(\|(\d+,)*\d+)*$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wS1lS3/1)

Both of these use the same general approach. First you create an expression `X` that matches one element of the sequence. To allow multiple of them separated by a delimiter `D`, you use the form:

```
^X(DX)*$
```

Comment: Yes that can be good I think but let me make some benchmarks on it as compared to regex because I will be having alot of strings. But I must wait until someone suggests a regex so I can compare the two

Comment: I changed my mind, there's a simple regexp for the first.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks Barmar. That's excellent catch **^X(DX)*$**. And I am also glad that I was almost there. Thanks alot. Your both regex worked like charm,

Answer (score 0):

What you want to see in results only strings that have not in it to ur 1 regexp?
For the second, try this:

```
/^(((\d+,)*\d+)[\|]?)+$/
```

It is better:

```
((?:\d+,?)+[|]?)?+
```

Comment: I have already defined my required output strings for first one with examples

Comment: This will allow **983,9,4|**. It fails on this

Comment: Your "better" version still allows `|` at the end of the string.

Comment: It also allows comma before pipe, like **939,9,|**